# How do I find a finish time by using a start time and hours per day in google sheets/ excell?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create rosters on google sheets but the only information I get is a start time and the hours worked that day, example: 7am, 2.36h worked, is there a formula I can use to calculate the finish time from these?

I know I can convert the 2.63h to minutes in a separate column and then use

```
=TIME(HOUR(D2),MINUTE(D2)+P2,SECOND(D2))
```

but I want to cut out the extra column.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=D2+TEXT(P2/1440*60, "hh:mm")
```

[image]

[image]